# How to write my project contribution in graduate application essay?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, research-process, united-states

I am applying for PhD position in the USA. In the application, I have to write a essay on my research experience. Its not a SOP, rather how I worked there, why, findings, what were my contributions, techniques I learned etc.
I have few publications and some of them were entirely done by me. My supervisor guided and when the manuscript was written, it was checked by other post docs or professors and that how their name is also in my paper.
My question is how to write it in the essay?

Answer (score 1):

Simply describe the nature of each project and a title, perhaps the title of a publication if possible. and note that the work was done as part of coursework. The implication will be that the work is yours and also that there was some feedback on it.

If the others are co-authors you can describe your work/role as "principal investigator", but make sure that the others agree with that characterization.

Comment: Actually none of them were done as a part of coursework, I work as a research assistant. All of them where independent work. I asked the graduate coordinator who suggested to write my research experiences like an abstract of a research article.

Comment: That is fine. Just tell it like it is.